# Setup Timer on jQuery PopUp

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code for a newsletter popup and I want to set a delay on it to pop-up after about a minute:

```
function beginNewsletterForm() {
    jQuery.fancybox({
        'padding': '0px',
        'autoScale': true,
        'transitionIn': 'fade',
        'transitionOut': 'fade',
        'type': 'inline',
        'href': '#newsletter_popup',
        'onComplete': function() {
            $.cookie('newsletter_popup', 'shown');
        },
        'tpl': { 
            closeBtn: '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close fancybox-newsletter-close" href="javascript:;"></a>' 
        },
        'helpers': {
            overlay : {
                locked  : false
            }
        }
    });
    jQuery('#newsletter_popup').trigger('click');
}

</script>
```

I thought I could add something like the following after transitionOut:

```
        'setTimeout': '5000'
```

And adjust the time as needed (I believe the above is 5 seconds), but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you expect after the timeout period expires ? Close the popup or display the popup after the timeout is reached?

Comment: The popup has a close button. Either the user submits their email address or it closes. This is all working as it should, I just need the popup itself to delay opening (at the moment it just opens as soon as the page is launched)

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, you need the popup itself to open with a delay

According to the fancybox [API docs](http://fancybox.net/api), currently there's no option to specify `timeout` period in the parameter-list of fancybox() function.

However, you can keep the `jQuery('#newsletter_popup').trigger('click')` (that triggers the opening of fancybox) within `setTimeout` with an expiry time of 5 seconds(5000 milliseconds).

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  jQuery('#newsletter_popup').trigger('click');
}, 5000);
```

Here's the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5EV8r/771/)

Comment: Thanks, I replaced this instead of 'jQuery('#newsletter_popup').trigger('click');' but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Just to confirm I don't want the box to disappear after 5 seconds - I want it to APPEAR after 5 seconds (at the moment it launches right away)

Comment: @IVCatalina: Hi I just checked the code at my end and its working fine. The fancybox is APPEARING after 5 seconds(from the moment you open the link). Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5EV8r/772/)

Answer (score 0):

try 
setTimeout(function(){jQuery('#newsletter_popup').trigger('click');},5000);

Comment: Thanks, I replaced this instead of 'jQuery('#newsletter_popup').trigger('click');' but it didn't seem to make any difference

Comment: Just to confirm I don't want the box to disappear after 5 seconds - I want it to APPEAR after 5 seconds (at the moment it launches right away)